# Need help connecting Flask-SQLAlchemy to MS SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: python, t-sql, flask-sqlalchemy

Having difficulty with getting the right connection to the database:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

engine = SQLAlchemy.create_engine()

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql-pyodbc://EVERETT-
PC\\SQLEXPRESS/iNcentDev?trusted_connection=yes'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class Payroll(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pay.PayRoll'
    pk = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    CreateDate = db.Column('CreateDate', db.DateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER_NAME;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=password")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```